# Trouble with PHPexcel removing leading zeros

Tags: php, opencart, phpexcel

I have the code below but when I run my CSV though the import process my leading zeros are gone. For example, I have a field with a number such as "0010" but after it comes from the below code the number is "10". Anybody have a suggestion?

```html
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 
 function ci_import($inputFileName){
  
   //echo "calling....";exit;
   
  try {
   $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
   $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
   $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) 
   . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
  }
  
  $sheets = count($objPHPExcel->getAllSheets());
  //echo $sheets;
  //echo "<pre>";
  $arr=array();
  foreach($objPHPExcel->getAllSheets() as $sheet){
   $title = $sheet->getTitle();
   $arr[$title]=array();
   $rows= array();
   // fetch the data
   foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) 
   {
    $cols= array();
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell)
    {
     $cols[]=$cell->getValue();
    }
    $rows[] = $cols;
   }
   $arr[$title]=$rows;
   
   
     }
  
  return $arr;
  print_r( $arr);
  
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Numbers don't have leading zeroes; but PHPExcel's CSV Reader will recognise that the value `0010` is numeric and convert it to a number `10`, which is perfectly correct, and (just for reference) is exactly what the MS Excel CSV Reader does.

If you want to treat this value as a string, or to format it as a 4-digit number with leading zeroes, then you want to create a custom binder that specifies this as a rule for importing the value.

```
class PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder extends PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder
    implements PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder 
{ 
    public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null) 
    { 
        // sanitize UTF-8 strings 
        if (is_string($value)) { 
            $value = PHPExcel_Shared_String::SanitizeUTF8($value); 
        } 

        // Implement your own override logic 
        if (is_string($value) && $value[0] == '0') { 
            // Here, we're just enforcing that the value should be treated
            //   as a string, but we could convert it to a numeric and apply
            //   a format mask to the cell instead
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING); 
            return true; 
        } 

        // Not bound yet? Use default value parent... 
        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value); 
    } 
}
```

To avoid any problems with the autoloader, create this in the /Classes/PHPExcel/Cell directory. Otherwise, give the class your own non-PHPExcel name, and ensure that it's loaded independently.

Then, before loading the file, indicate that your custom binder should be used:

```
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_MyValueBinder() );
```